# Can I read in objective lens current using DM script?

Tags: dm-script

I am wondering if I can get the objective lens current by some commands in DM script. I tried to figure it out in the help file, but I only found the command to get objective stigmation (EMGetObjectiveStigmation), but not the one for objective lens current.

Comment: "Focus" is the objective lens (in TEM), so you want EMGetFocus() etc.

Comment: The EMGetFocus() returns a "relative" defocus value. Is there a script command can read the "absolute" objective lens values?